# Unable to set values in NSMutableDictionary in Unit tests

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing, ios

I am writing unit tests in GHUnit test framework. I have a NSMutableDictionary detailsDict defined in my Application delegate.

In my application delegate I set some values in & save it.
It works fine in the app but when I try to call a method to set values on it in unit tests I am not able to set any value & dictionary remains empty.

In the test case I alloc init my appDelegate. Message a method from this object which sets a few keys but When I check for its values it remains empty.

Is there anything I dont know about unit testing or what am I missing....?

Any answers pointers will be highly appreciated.

EDIT: I got it I had to separately alloc init the detailsDic variable
like this

```
#ifdef UNIT_TESTING
    detailsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
#endif
```

Still open to other answers on other ways of doing this.

Comment: You should post the code of your app delegate. You should not have to init this separately - apparently something is going on that's different. Where in the app delegate did you allocate the `detailsDict`? Maybe in `applicationDidStart:withOptions:`? This is - of course - not called if you just alloc/init the delegate in your test manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't alloc and init a variable. You can alloc and init an object, and indeed you do need to alloc and init this NSMutableDictionary object *somewhere*.

The proper place to do that is somewhere that will run both for your application and for every test case. The app delegate's `init` method is probably a good choice.

That said, I'd say that your app delegate should not exist at all in your unit tests, because your unit tests are not an application. You should split out whatever functionality you mean to test into one or more separate controllers, which you create and work with from the app delegate and from the relevant unit tests.

Comment: Thank you Peter your answers are always helpful. May you learn more & help us more ;). We're lucky to have you here.